# A linear mapping has finite kernel and closed image is equivalent to a statement regarding sequences.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I have been reading about Fredholm operators and came across [these](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-965-geometry-of-manifolds-fall-2004/lecture-notes/lecture16_17.pdf) notes.

My question is about Lemma 16.17 on the second page. This lemma states the following:

Lemma 16.17: Let $X$ and $Y$ be Banach spaces and $T:X \rightarrow Y$ a bounded linear map. The following are equivalent:

1. $\text{Ker}(T)$ is finite dimensional and $\text{Im}(T)$ is closed
2. Every bounded sequence $\left \{ x_{i} \right \} \subset X$ with $Tx_{i}$ convergent has a convergent subsequence.

I am having a hard time seeing the reverse direction ($2. \implies 1.$).  In particular I am interested in 2. implying $\text{Ker}(T)$ is finite dimensional (the image being closed was covered in [another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3539601/equivalence-between-closed-range-finite-dimensional-kernel-and-a-statement-ab) question). It seems to me like this is connected to the Bolzano-Weierstrass property which [only holds](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2508834/counterexample-to-bolzano-weierstrass-in-infinite-dimension) in finite dimensional spaces, but I am not sure how or where the convergence of $Tx_{i}$ comes in.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take a bounded sequence in $\ker T$ and use 2. to show that is has a convergent subsequence. Conclude that the (relative) closed unit ball of $\ker T$ is compact and thus the kernel is of finite dimension.

Comment: Ah thank you.  All $Tx_{i} = 0$ so all subsequences converge to the same point.  So the $Tx_{i}$ condition in 2. is automatically satisfied.  Appreciate the help.